# Getting errors with Yesod's Persistent module when declaring database tables/columns

Tags: mysql, database, haskell, web, yesod

I'm trying to use Yesod's Persistent module in order to build my database for my website (done in Haskell with Yesod). Here is my models file:

```
User
    idAccount AccountId Int
    userLastName Text Maybe
    userFirstName Text Maybe
    userAge Int Maybe
    userSex Text Maybe
    userEMail Text
    UniqueUserEMail userEMail
Account
    accountName Text
    accountPassword Text
    accountCreatedDate UTCTime default=CURRENT_TIME
    accountLastLogin UTCTime default=CURRENT_TIME
    UniqueAccountName accountName
```

When I first compiled, I got the following error:

```
Model.hs:14:7:                                                                                                                                                                   
    Not in scope: type constructor or class `UTCTime'                                                                                                                            
    In the result of the splice:                                                                                                                                                 
      $(persistFileWith lowerCaseSettings "config/models")                                                                                                                       
    To see what the splice expanded to, use -ddump-splices                                                                                                                       
    In the second argument of `share', namely                                                                                                                                    
      `$(persistFileWith lowerCaseSettings "config/models")'
    In the expression:
      share
        [mkPersist sqlOnlySettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"]
        ($(persistFileWith lowerCaseSettings "config/models"))
```

I then added the `time` module in my `build-depends` section in my .cabal file. This removed the last error, but I now have the following errors:

```
Foundation.hs:135:22:
    Not in scope: data constructor `UniqueUser'
    Perhaps you meant `UniqueDef' (imported from Yesod)

Foundation.hs:140:23:
    `userIdent' is not a (visible) field of constructor `User'

Foundation.hs:141:23:
    `userPassword' is not a (visible) field of constructor `User'
```

For the first error, to my understanding (I.E., what I understand of the uniqueness constraint section of the [yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent)), if I want to make a field unique, I just have to add a line at the end of the table definition starting with the string "Unique" with a space and then the name of the field that I want to be unique. Am I mistaken?

As for the last two errors, I do not have those fields declared anywhere, so I do not know why they are there. Any insights on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the source of my errors. Since I am using the scaffold site, there is already some stuff implemented for me. One of those things is the Yesod Auth module which was tied with the default Persistent module database structure. So when I changed the database structure in my `models` file, it was not compatible anymore with the default Auth module code in the `Foundation.hs` file, namely the getAuthId function:

```
getAuthId creds = runDB $ do
    x <- getBy $ UniqueUser $ credsIdent creds
    case x of
        Just (Entity uid _) -> return $ Just uid
        Nothing -> do
            fmap Just $ insert User
                ( userIdent = credsIdent creds
                , userPassword = Nothing
                )
```

I do not know how to modify this code to fit my purposes yet, so I will update this answer once I do.

Comment: try this one. this works for me.  

`authenticate creds = runDB $ do   
        x <- getBy $ UniqueUser $ credsIdent creds  
        return $ case x of  
            Just (Entity uid _) -> Authenticated uid  
            Nothing -> UserError InvalidLogin `

Answer (score 1):

The following compiles for me on `persistent-1.3.1.1, persistent-mongoDB-1.4.1, persistent-template 1.3.1.4`. I've listed out the pragmas and the modules in case they are a source of the problem.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}                                                                                                                                                                              
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.TH
import Database.Persist.MongoDB
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX (getPOSIXTime,posixSecondsToUTCTime)
import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Time (UTCTime,TimeOfDay)


let mongoSettings = (mkPersistSettings (ConT ''MongoBackend)) {mpsGeneric = False}
    in share [mkPersist mongoSettings] [persistLowerCase|
User
    idAccount AccountId Int
    userLastName Text Maybe
    userFirstName Text Maybe
    userAge Int Maybe
    userSex Text Maybe
    userEMail Text
    UniqueUserEMail userEMail
Account
    accountName Text
    accountPassword Text
    accountCreatedDate UTCTime default=CURRENT_TIME
    accountLastLogin UTCTime default=CURRENT_TIME
    UniqueAccountName accountName
|]
```

Comment: You should really add an explanation as to what the OP did incorrectly and why they need to do the things you did.

Comment: Sure; Although the code is actually exactly the same. Noted that on top of the answer.